# Rspec - How to test module in Service layer

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I have ArticleService module in my service layer(app/services/article_service.rb), and I want to test this module and method. The below is the rspec code. The result is false. I think the reason is the test doesnt call `ArticleService.create`, but I dont know how to do it.

```
    module ArticleService

      module_function

      def create
        Article.update(publish: 1)
      end
    end


    require 'rails_helper'

    describe ArticleService do
      describe '#create' do
        it 'update article publish' do
          article = create(:article, property: 0)
          expect(article.publish).to eq 1
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this is supposed to work... `Article.update(publish: 1) ` is calling a class method `.update` ... how is it supposed to know which `article` instance to update?

Comment: Ah that is the point... I have no idea how to call this method. If I could do, I could pass some arguments for example article_id

Comment: You could just call it with the module as receiver.  `ArticleService.create` and if you need to pass parameters you can do that `ArticleService.create(id: 123)` and then in the service `def create(options)` and in the method reference `article = Article.find(options[:id])`

Comment: is it like ArticleService.create(id: 123) in before statement or in it statement?

Comment: You're creating the article in the `it` statement so you can't run `ArticleService.create` in before as you don't know the new article's id at that point.